# Entity Framework 4.0; Is there a limit on the number of objects(tables,views,sprocs) it will handle?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database with many tables, views and sprocs. If I try to create a data model that includes everything, it errors out on the creation of the class file. If I try to create a model with just the views, it works fine. Is there a limit or is there something in a config file somewhere that needs to be tweaked?

Comment: Please be more specific about the error.

Comment: it creates the class file, but, the only thing in it is a message that it failed and to check the "Error List" wherever that is. The diagram appears to have been created with no errors.

Comment: ...and when you look in the Error List (hint: View -> Error List) you see...? What, exactly?

Comment: no errors, however there are many warnings and messages. Most of them have to do with missing primary key. (on views as well as tables). If I create 3 separate models, it works fine.

Comment: I give up. If you don't want to give out the information required to help you with your problem, then you won't get any help. I've asked twice, and you still won't transcribe the messages you see. Nobody can read your mind, and *the specific messages are important.*

Comment: I was not trying to be hard. I am really not getting much in the way of errors. In Model.Designer.cs all I see is "// Seeing this comment implies that the code generation for file 'C:\Websites\Market Rediness Checklist 2.0\App_Code\Model.edmx'
// failed. See the ErrorList for details.". When I go to the Error List, there are no errors. There are Messages and Warnings. As I looked thru those, all I see is "No Primary Key" on the views. If I generate 3 separate Models, all works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a model with just the tables and/or procs? I'm not aware of a size limit but could it be possible the creation of the model is taking so long your SQL connection is timing out? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Yes, if I only do the tables or views, it works fine. That is why I thought there might be a size limitation.